# Need to use a loop to print out the total number in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

Just trying to figure out how to print this out to look like this:

```
The total team points is 2232.00 
The two point percent is 41.13
The three point percent is 32.06
The foul shot percent is 66.86
```

Rather than what I have now, which keeps going through the loop and printing it out indivudally through the team rather than adding it all up together. Like this:

```
The total team points is: 516.0
The two point percent is: 0.46783626
The three point percent is: 0.26865673
The foul shot percent is: 0.625
The total team points is: 590.0
The two point percent is: 0.38135594
The three point percent is: 0.3037037
The foul shot percent is: 0.7579618
The total team points is: 408.0
The two point percent is: 0.43459916
etc...
```

This is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < team.size(); i++) {
    float points = (float) (2 * (team.get(i).getmade1() + team.get(i).getmade2() + team.get(i).getmade3()));
    float twopercent = (float) (team.get(i).gettwoPercent());
    float threepercent = (float) (team.get(i).getthreePercent());
    float foulpercent = (float) (team.get(i).getfoulPercent());
    System.out.println("The total team points is: " + points);
    System.out.println("The two point percent is: " + twopercent);
    System.out.println("The three point percent is: " + threepercent);
    System.out.println("The foul shot percent is: " + foulpercent);
}
outputStream.println(team);
```

The rest of my work for reference is this:

```
public class fileStreamtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        ArrayList<BBall> team = new ArrayList<BBall>();
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/Users/Gracie/Documents/workspace/Lab7/src/team.txt"));
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("/Users/Gracie/Documents/workspace/Lab7/src/team_stat.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem opening files" + e.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // Here you declare and initialize the varibales you need in loop
        int num;
        String fname;
        String lname;
        int twoMade;
        int twoAttempt;
        int threeMade;
        int threeAttempt;
        int foulMade;
        int foulAttempt;

        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            // read variable by variable across the line
            num = inputStream.nextInt();
            lname = inputStream.next();
            fname = inputStream.next();
            twoMade = inputStream.nextInt();
            twoAttempt = inputStream.nextInt();
            threeMade = inputStream.nextInt();
            threeAttempt = inputStream.nextInt();
            foulMade = inputStream.nextInt();
            foulAttempt = inputStream.nextInt();

            // then use all these variables to make a BBallPlayer and add to the arraylist
            BBall player = new BBall(num, fname, lname, twoMade, twoAttempt, threeMade, threeAttempt, foulMade,
                    foulAttempt);
            team.add(player);
        }
        // keep reading a line until there is no more input

        // using a loop go through the arraylist and get the team totals OF THE NUMBER
        // OF POINTS
        // prints out totals et

        for (int i = 0; i < team.size(); i++) {
            float points = (float) (2 * (team.get(i).getmade1() + team.get(i).getmade2() + team.get(i).getmade3()));
            float twopercent = (float) (team.get(i).gettwoPercent());
            float threepercent = (float) (team.get(i).getthreePercent());
            float foulpercent = (float) (team.get(i).getfoulPercent());
            System.out.println("The total team points is: " + points);
            System.out.println("The two point percent is: " + twopercent);
            System.out.println("The three point percent is: " + threepercent);
            System.out.println("The foul shot percent is: " + foulpercent);
        }

        outputStream.println(team);

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }// end method
}// end class
```

and the other class

```
public class BBall {
    private int number;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int made2;
    private int att2;
    private int made3;
    private int att3;
    private int made1;
    private int att1;

    public BBall(int n, String lN, String fN, int m2, int a2, int m3, int a3, int m1, int a1) {
        number = n;
        lastName = lN;
        firstName = fN;
        made2 = m2;
        att2 = a2;
        made3 = m3;
        att3 = a3;
        made1 = m1;
        att1 = a1;

    }

    public int getnumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getlastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getfirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public int getmade2() {
        return made2;
    }

    public int getatt2() {
        return att2;
    }

    public int getmade3() {
        return made3;
    }

    public int getatt3() {
        return att3;
    }

    public int getmade1() {
        return made1;
    }

    public int getatt1() {
        return att1;
    }

    public void setnumber(int n) {
        number = n;
    }

    public void setlastName(String lN) {
        lastName = lN;
    }

    public void setfirstName(String fN) {
        firstName = fN;
    }

    public void setmade2(int m2) {
        made2 = m2;
    }

    public void setatt2(int a2) {
        att2 = a2;
    }

    public void setmade3(int m3) {
        made3 = m3;
    }

    public void setatt3(int a3) {
        att3 = a3;
    }

    public void setmade1(int m1) {
        made1 = m1;
    }

    public void setatt1(int a1) {
        att1 = a1;
    }

    public float gettwoPercent() {
        float twoPercent = (float) made2 / (float) att2;
        return twoPercent;
    }

    public float getthreePercent() {
        float threePercent = (float) made3 / (float) att3;
        return threePercent;
    }

    public float getfoulPercent() {
        float foulPercent = (float) made1 / (float) att1;
        return foulPercent;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return " " + firstName + " " + lastName + " \n Two point percent: " + gettwoPercent()
                + " \n Three point percent: " + getthreePercent() + "\n Foul shot percent: " + getfoulPercent();
    }

}// end class
```

Text file:

```
25 DEMERY James 160 342 18 67 80 128
1 NEWKIRK Shavar 135 354 41 135 119 157
33 FUNK Taylor 103 237 70 173 31 37
0  KIMBLE Lamarr 4 11 2 4 0 1
15 CLOVER Chris 81 207 26 80 22 43
24 OLIVA Pierfrancesc 56 121 12 45 31 64
5 ROBINSON Nick 46 115 6 31 42 55
12 LONGPRE Anthony 34 111 18 56 10 16
22 EDWARDS Lorenzo 10 39 7 32 4 5
10 BLOUNT Gerald 2 2 0 0 0 0
32 WILLIAMS Jai 5 10 0 0 3 5
23 LODGE Markell 5 6 0 0 1 3
3 BOOTH Michael 1 2 1 2 0 0
21 THOMPSON Kyle 0 1 0 0 2 2
11 FREEMAN Toliver 0 2 0 2 0 0
13 VEGA Christian 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Before you start, please indent code so that it can be read.

Comment: Add the values together in the loop (Adding the value of the currrent iteration to the total inside the loop) and print the total values after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should calculate the sum before you print the result :

```
        float points = 0 ;
        float twopercent = 0 ;
        float threepercent = 0 ;
        float foulpercent = 0 ;

        for (int i = 0; i<team.size(); i++){
             points = points + (float) (2 * (team.get(i).getmade1() + team.get(i).getmade2() + team.get(i).getmade3()));
             twopercent = twopercent +  (float) (team.get(i).gettwoPercent());
             threepercent = threepercent + (float) (team.get(i).getthreePercent());
             foulpercent = foulpercent + (float) (team.get(i).getfoulPercent());

        }

        System.out.println("The total team points is: " + points );
        System.out.println("The two point percent is: " + twopercent);
        System.out.println("The three point percent is: " + threepercent);
        System.out.println("The foul shot percent is: " + foulpercent);
```

Comment: In my opinion this and OP calculations for all teams would be incorrect. Since percentages will mean different values for different teams.

Comment: Which will be false. Why is this upvoted? You have to calculate points (made1, made2, mde3) for all the teams, and only then percentages.

Comment: this is just an exemple from me , if the sum is false , he should do the right calculation, but he should use a variables before the loop , and print after the loop

Comment: that's fair enough.

Comment: thanks, this was the method i was looking for. the calculations, for the %, is wrong on my end, but I fixed them. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

While Azzabi Haythem answer is correct, calculations itself are not.

I would get all sums of the points of all teams first, then calculate percentages.

```
float points = 0 ;

// foul
int made1 = 0 ;
int att1 = 0;

// two points
int made2 = 0 ;
int att2 = 0;

// three points
int made3 = 0 ;
int att3 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<team.size(); i++){
    points = points + (float) (2 * (team.get(i).getmade1() + team.get(i).getmade2() + team.get(i).getmade3()));

    // foul
    made1 = made1 + team.get(i).getmade1(i);
    att1 = att1 + team.get(i).getAtt1(i);

    // two points
    made2 = made2 + team.get(i).getmade2(i);
    att2 = att2 + team.get(i).getAtt2(i);

    // three points
    made3 = made3 + team.get(i).getmade3(i);
    att3 = att3 + team.get(i).getAtt3(i);
}


float foulPercent = (float) made1 / (float) att1;
float twoPercent = (float) made2 / (float) att2;
float threePercent = (float) made3 / (float) att3;

System.out.println("The total team points is: " + points );
System.out.println("The two point percent is: " + twoPercent);
System.out.println("The three point percent is: " + threePercent);
System.out.println("The foul shot percent is: " + foulPercent);
```

Comment: I realized my mistake in the calculations when I was getting an output of NaN and also it just didn't make sense after looking at it, thanks for this, it was very helpful. There was an error in the guide my professor handed out, and his set example is wrong also after seeing this output ~